# Silverlight - WCF error

Tags: wcf, silverlight, protocolexception

I have a problem consuming a WCF service through a silver light application, the problem suddenly happened today, the same piece of code was running successfully 1 month ago, 
I got the following exception:

```
{System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:22bb2c0b-5a1b-498d-9539-a19fa401d509+id=6";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 626 bytes of the response were: '
--uuid:22bb2c0b-5a1b-498d-9539-a19fa401d509+id=6
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><LargeImageResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><LargeImageResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:int>1</a:int><a:int>2</a:int><a:int>3</a:int><a:int>4</a:int></LargeImageResult></LargeImageResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:22bb2c0b-5a1b-498d-9539-a19fa401d509+id=6--
'.
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at AbdenTestSilverlight.FileIndexingService.FileIndexingServiceClient.FileIndexingServiceClientChannel.EndLargeImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at AbdenTestSilverlight.FileIndexingService.FileIndexingServiceClient.AbdenTestSilverlight.FileIndexingService.IFileIndexingService.EndLargeImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at AbdenTestSilverlight.FileIndexingService.FileIndexingServiceClient.OnEndLargeImage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-Type: application/xop+xml;` suggests that the wcf service is configured to use MTOM encoding on the server which is not supported by Silverlight.

I am not sure how this could have worked earlier unless there has been a change in the endpoint recently causing this error.